# Tesserect-ocr text wrapping

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am developing invoice text extraction project with tesseract-ocr. I have a problem with irregular text wrapping. When I applied tesseract to the Image1, because tesseract-ocr reads line by line, some words are split as in Image2 and the rest of the word is written on the bottom line. How can I fix this?

Image1
[image: Image1]

Image2
[image: Image2]

Comment: Have you tried to contact the people behind tesseract?

Comment: No I didn't. I searched tesseract-ocr github page but I didn't find anything for my issue